# how to stop offset at a certain cell in excel

Tags: excel

I got a simple question in Excel.
I want to use offset formula from a cell with text to downwards(through black cells), and stop offset when met a cell with text.

[image]

for example, I want to display 5000, which is next to 2, but the offset will begin from the number 1.

Any comments will be really helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your single example is not clear. What are the cell references in question? Where should the formula be placed? Also, `OFFSET` is a volatile function, and so should be avoided where alternatives exist (which is often the case).

Comment: Simply show your input and expected output.